How to randomly wiggle vertices?
I have this object (flat plane) with a Lattice modifier, I want to randomly wiggle the position of each vertex on the Lattice individually - how's best to do this? Similar behaviour to wiggle expression in After Effects. Even better if I can "posterise" this movement to about 8fps. (I'm a 2D Animator experimenting with 3D, sorry if i've not got the right terminology!)

Thank you
